# NRF24L01 Python Library for Raspberry

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I've tried to use this library to write test function for NRF24L01 on Raspberry Pi 3 :https://github.com/jpbarraca/pynrf24

I need from that code to switch between listing and writing mode during runtime. Unfortunately because of the library I've got errors .

Can anyone tell me how to fix them? Or at least give me some other library that would work properly?

SPI on Raspberry is enebled 
as it was in issues (https://github.com/jpbarraca/pynrf24/issues/38) : I've also tried set begin(0,0... but that resulted with:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "TestNRF.py", line 8, in
>
> ```
> radio.begin(0, 0, "P8_23", "P8_24")  # Set CE and IRQ pins   File "/home/pi/Commander/NRF24L01/nrf24.py", line 232, in begin
> GPIO.setup(self.ce_pin, GPIO.OUT)
> ```
>
> ValueError: Channel must be an integer or list/tuple of integers

I've also tried : https://github.com/BLavery/lib_nrf24
but I've couldn't find from where can I get module virtGPIO

```
from NRF24L01.nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import struct

pipes = [[0xe7, 0xe7, 0xe7, 0xe7, 0xe7], [0xc2, 0xc2, 0xc2, 0xc2, 0xc2]]

radio = NRF24()
radio.begin(1, 0, "P8_23", "P8_24")  # Set CE and IRQ pins
radio.setRetries(15, 15)
radio.setPayloadSize(5)
radio.setChannel(0x60)

radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_250KBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MAX)


def writeMode():
    radio.stopListening()
    radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[1])
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[0])

    # radio.startListening()
    # radio.stopListening()


def listenMode():
    radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0])
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])

    # radio.startListening()
    # radio.stopListening()

    radio.startListening()

    i = 0
    while True:
        listenMode()
        print("Listen Mode")
        recv_buffer = []
        pipe = [0]
        if radio.available(pipe, True):
            radio.read(recv_buffer)
            values = struct.unpack_from('HBBB',recv_buffer)
            print(values)
        else:
            writeMode()
            print("Write Mode")
            msg = struct.pack('HBBB', 3000, 243, 234, 254)
            radio.write(msg)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        i = +1
        if i == 4:
            exit()
```

> Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "TestNRF.py", line 8,
>   in
>
> ```
> radio.begin(1, 0, "P8_23", "P8_24")  # Set CE and IRQ pins   File "/home/pi/Commander/NRF24L01/nrf24.py", line 213, in begin
> self.spidev.open(major, minor)
> ```
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future dummies like me (cause I don't think there's any bigger idiot)
Raspberry Pi 3 B+ has only SPI0 which means that that line :

```
radio.begin(1, 0, "P8_23", "P8_24")
```

must be changed to that:

```
radio.begin(0, 0, "P8_23", "P8_24")
```

also remember to set pins for CE and IRQ (e.g.):

```
radio.begin(0, 0, 23, 24)
```

good picture for that:
[Raspberry 3 B+ pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAdMW.png)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in my pi 4b by enabling SPI interface in raspy-config.